# probability of arrivals of buses and waiting time

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let a person at a place at a time uniformly distributed between 6 p.m.
and 7 p.m., and boards the first bus that arrives. There are two types of
buses that arrive between 7 a.m. and midnight: those that head to town
Z arrive every 15 minutes starting at 7 a.m., and those that head to town
Y arrive every 15 minutes starting at 7:05 a.m.. (a) How long does the person
wait, on the average and what proportion of days does he go to Z ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 0):

The following figure depicts $12$ different possibilities to arrive:

[image]

The coloring tells which bus will be catched. In the case of $1,3,4,6,7,9,10,12$ the average waiting time will be $2.5$ minutes. In the case of $2,5,8,11$ the average waiting time will be $7.5$ minutes. The probability of arriving at any of the intervals is $\frac1{12} $.

Now, the average waiting time is

$$2.5\frac8{12}+7.5\frac4{12}=4\text{ minutes}.$$

Furthermore there are $4$ positions to get to the blue location and there are $8$ positions to get to the red location. The corresponding probabilities are the

$$P_{\text{blue}}=\frac4{12}=\frac13,\ P_{\text{red}}=\frac8{12}=\frac23.$$

Comment: Could you suggested some other approaches to solve such problems? Your answer clarifies it nevertheless.

Comment: @lal: Why do you need another approach?

Comment: To expand my horizons, isn't mandatory. Thanks nevertheless.